# network connectivity testing in a private network

Tags: linux-networking

I have a system with 2 network cards. One connected to the public network, another is connected to a private network for testing.
The port for private network is connected to a juniper switch configured dhcp service like as below:

```
system {
    host-name sw-juniper-4550;
    auto-snapshot;
    root-authentication {
        encrypted-password "$1$kl8CbOgC$bZZVKTwrt8xxxxxxxx"; ## SECRET-DATA
    }
    services {
        ssh {
            root-login allow;
            protocol-version v2;
        }
        dhcp {
            pool 192.168.0.0/24 {
                address-range low 192.168.0.10 high 192.168.0.200;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have not configured a router as it will make the host to be with 2 default route, which will cause connection issue. The question is how can I test the connection for the private network port on the system? As it is private, it can not ping public urls like "www.google.com", should I connect another system to the private switch and configure a static ip like "192.168.0.100" to be the "ping target"? Is that a must?

I have tried to ping 192.168.0.1 on the system, it works! I'm very confused about it, as my range is "192.168.0.10~192.168.0.200", there is no 192.168.0.1, who owns this ip? for what purpose? If this network connectivity testing valid to ping "192.168.0.1"?

Comment: You test a network connection by checking connectivity to a device on that network, or connectivity to a device that can be reached via that network. Indeed, Google can't be reached via your private network, therefore ping an address on the private network. As to 192.168.0.1, could the DHCP server have this address? What MAC address is associated with 192.168.0.1? The upper three octets of the MAC address encode the vendor. Use `ip neighbour` or `ip n` to get the MAC address, then find an OUI lookup service on the internet to get a clue.